# Keyboard and mouse input not working login

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, xorg, mouse

After a reboot of my 20.04 I have lost keyboard and mouse input at the login screen. I am using a physical desktop and don't have touch screen so can use virtual keyboard to log in.

When I enter into recovery mode (or move on grub menu) then keyboard works fine. And when I boot into live CD then keyboard and mouse work fine.

I have looked at other posts which mention to install xserver-xorg-input-all and in recovery mode I have checked and this is installed. I tried to remove and reinstall but this didn't help either.

Any ideas what I can do to get keyboard and mouse working again? Was working fine and then suddenly one day I rebooted and it wasn't.

Comment: Do you remember if you tried to install or modify some stuff in your system before the problem happened? Are you able to log in with for example an external USB keyboard and an external mouse? If yes can you add the output of ```lsusb```, ```lspci``` and ```xinput list``` to your post?